# How can a method tell which view controller called it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to get the current view controller in my own method. I mean i have two view controllers which are calling a same method. In that i want to diffentiate from which view controller class is calling that method.

Please help me out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets say `myCommonMethod:` is the common function called from both the view controller , you could check your `viewController` whether it's the member of a class or not using `isMemberOfClass:` method of `NSObject`.

```
-(void) myCommonMethod:(UIViewController*) aViewController
{
      if([aViewController isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MyFirstController")])
      {
      }
      else if([aViewController isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MySecondController")])
      {  

      }
}
```

Comment: i get this error: request for member 'navigationController' in something not a structure or union

Comment: I am using EGORefereshTableHeaderView , In that i am calling refreshLastUpdatedDate function. This function is called by two views.so the last updated date time is not maintained properly.i am not sure how to use the EGORefreshTableHeaderView class between multiple views...Please help me out

Comment: Of course this will break if you refactor your class names. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13624342/1431728 for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 39):

If it is a navigation based app, you can get the current view controller by,

```
UIViewController *currentVC = self.navigationController.visibleViewController;
```

Comment: I have a follow-on question. How would you get the current detailVC in a splitView app.. Thanks

Comment: @David DelMonte, Sorry for the delayed reply, but I am not that familiar with SplitView. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If both of your view controllers are calling same function then you can pass `self` as a parameter in that method for this you can write function as -

```
-(void) functionName:(UIViewController*) viewController
```