# Get UIViewController class name in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am getting viewControllers on navigationController stack as follows. Now I need to check if controller on top is one of known vc. How to get vc class name in order to compare it? Thank you.

```
NSArray *viewContrlls=[[self navController] viewControllers];
[viewContrlls lastObject]
```

something like,

```
if ([[viewContrlls lastObject] name] isEqualToString @"viewControllerName"){
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use this It may Help's you

```
 NSString *CurrentSelectedCViewController = NSStringFromClass([[((UINavigationController *)viewController1) visibleViewController] class]);
```

Answer (score 14):

The most common technique is to use `-isKindOfClass`:

```
if ([[viewContrells lastObject] isKindOfClass:MyViewController.class]]) {
    // ...
}
```

Using `NSStringFromClass` to compare strings is not a very nice solution because your code will break if you refactor the view controller to rename it.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ([NSStringFromClass([[viewContrlls lastObject] class]) isEqualToString: @"Whatever"]){
}
```

You could also use `-isKindOfClass` if you prefer to compare directly an instance to a specific class.

Answer (score -2):

Swift version:

```
static func getClassNameAsString(className: AnyObject) -> String {
    return _stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(className).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
}
```

Comment: unresolved identifier _stdlib_getDemangledTypeName.

I think you also have to tell which library we have to import.